# What are the possible dangers of removing the microwave shielding?

Tags: everyday-life, biophysics, microwaves, laboratory-safety

Would removing the shielding from a domestic microwave door allow the microwaves to cause damage to a consumer grade video camera, and if so, what damage would it cause?

Comment: I apologise in advance if this isn't the correct place to ask this.

Comment: Related http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128916/.  The last answer says the camera would suffer but gives no details.

Comment: Make sure you ensure your own survival before the camera's! Seriously. Make sure you know the dangers: microwave radiation is extremely hazardous to the eyes. Read this too http://www.microtechfactoryservice.com/safety.html#dischg This is not a recommended thing to do at all.

Comment: It depends of course on the distance. I am not recommending anything, but if I really needed to make a movie of something in a microwave, I would probably want to keep large parts of the mesh. Make larger holes in it, hope it won't get hot. And cut off the power cable immediately after I was done. Never get your eyes close to the thing.

Comment: Just echoing the @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance warning, I should have said BEWARE in my first comment. On the admittedly very extreme end of the scale of what you might undergo, here is a true story of a guy who stuck his head into a bigger version of a microwave oven, [Things Not To Do #1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoli_Bugorski)